# Convert a binary image to rgb

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors, rgb

I have RGB image that I converted to binary to do some processing(I'm working on watermarking) and in extraction watermaek I want to reconvert it back to its original color RGB, is it possible? I did some researchs on the internet but unfortunately I couldn't find a good answer. thank you in advance.

Comment: No. Its not possible to convert binary image to RGB. Just save the original RGB image in a different variable.

Comment: info is lost when you biniarize , what exactly are you planning on doing?

Comment: Processing done on a derived binary image can be used to create a **mask** for the original image. Is this what you are aiming at?

Comment: I'm actually working on image watermarking with RGB watermark( logo), but in embedding process I convert the watermark to binary. And then in extracting I extract the binary watermark and want to convert it to RGB so I can get it like the original.

Answer (score 2):

Binarization is a lossy opertation that loses information. There is no way to hallucinate this information back, unless you use the additional external input, e.g. the original image.

You can always use your binary image as a mask for example for operating on the original RGB image.

If you want an RGB formatted binary image, just copy the binary image into the three RGB channel. You will need to decide what RGB the binary non-zero value will be converted to, e.g. 1, 255, max-val etc.